# Win32Exception при вызове Process.Start для https ссылки

Tags: c#, winforms

В Windows Forms кнопка должна открывать видео с ютуба в браузере но в место этого выдаёт что исключение не обработано:

З.Ы. ссылка с embed/ без watch?v= и прочее тоже ничего не дают.

`System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: "An error occurred trying to start process 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdnMT1R1K60&t' with working directory 'C:\Users\User\source\repos\Redux\Redux\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows'. Не удается найти указанный файл."`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace Redux
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
    
            private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("https://www.youtube.com/watchv=FdnMT1R1K60&t");
            }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21835891/312041